# How to create reverse dynamic ssh port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up an ssh tunnel layout where:

1. client A (not ssh-server enabled) initiates ssh connection to server S
2. socks server is opened on server S:yyyy that tunnels all data via client A
3. client B connects socks server on server S, and tcp data routes via client A to the Internet

A possible solution would be to add a proxy server on Client A (binded to localhost:xxxx), and then run on client A `ssh -R yyyy:localhost:xxxx Server`. That would achieve the goal. But that's not as clean as using just ssh.

Is it possible to achieve this with just the ssh client on A and ssh-server on S? it's like reverse-dynamic-port-forwarding on ssh - creating `ssh -D` from A to S, and then somehow setup on this tunnel a second tunnel of `ssh -D` from S to A. Somewhat confusing, and not sure if possible.

Comment: Up to OpenSSH-6.7 I don't think it can be done simply, native socks proxy support works only in the direction ssh->sshd.

Answer (score 31):

[OpenSSH 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6) introduced reverse dynamic proxy as a native option. It is implemented entirely in the client, so the server does not need to be updated.

```
ssh -R 1080 server
```

Comment: But you still need the SOCKS server, otherwise you just have a reverse tunnel...

Comment: `-R` isn't dynamic, `-D` is

Comment: Previous comments are incorrect. Had they taken the time to read the release notes provided for OpenSSH 7.6 they would see the the `-R` flag was updated to also provide reverse dynamic SOCKS.  * ssh(1): add support for reverse dynamic forwarding. In this mode,
   ssh will act as a SOCKS4/5 proxy and forward connections
   to destinations requested by the remote SOCKS client. This mode
   is requested using extended syntax for the -R and RemoteForward
   options and, because it is implemented solely at the client,
   does not require the server be updated to be supported

Comment: is there a way to do this in th `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: I confirm it works great. Let's say you want your proxy client to be on host A and your socks proxy on host B. From host B, run `ssh -R 1080 userA@hostA`, then from host A, run `curl --socks5-hostname localhost:1080 https://www.google.com` and you'll get the result. Just to be sure the data went through the tunnel/proxy, close the ssh connection, re-run the curl command and you'll get `curl: (7) Failed to connect`

Answer (score 6):

I was just searching for this and came across the same (or similar) question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842021/).

On client A `ssh -R \*:24680:localhost:12345 serverS` and then (still on client A) `ssh -D 12345 localhost` [1]

You [need](https://superuser.com/questions/588591) to the `\*` bit so it will bind to server S's public IP address and not just localhost.

Then on client B simply connect to the socks server at `serverS:24680`

---

[1] EDIT: I just realized that this won't work if client A doesn't have SSH Server because it can't ssh itself. I was thinking of a setup where client A had an SSH Server but was not accessible by Server S. But a similar setup could still work if you can install a [socks server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Software) on client A and open it on port 12345.

Comment: It works, great

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether this helps anyone, here is a diagram for my setup that I managed to construct...

[image: SSH reverse tunnel with SOCKS proxying]

You will see two processes on MACHINE_B:

The SSH client connection to MACHINE_A (olive):

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:22344:127.0.0.1:4444 -i privkey.sshkey -N user_a@machine_a
```

The SSH client working as SOCKS server on port 4444 (dark green):

```
ssh -D localhost:4444 -N user_c@localhost
```

And one processes on MACHINE_A, the one playing server listening on port 22344 (olive).

The light green process on MACHINE_B should appear when the light green process on MACHINE_A asks for a connection...

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSSH 7.6 release note](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6)

> ### New Features
>
> - ssh(1): add support for reverse dynamic forwarding. In this mode,
>   ssh will act as a SOCKS4/5 proxy and forward connections    to
>   destinations requested by the remote SOCKS client. This mode    is
>   requested using extended syntax for the -R and RemoteForward
>   options and, because it is implemented solely at the client,    does
>   not require the server be updated to be supported.

review all types ...

#### local port forwarding

forward (= send) from local (`1111`) to a remote (=receive) (`2222`)

```bash
ssh -L localhost:1111:localhost:2222 remote
```

use case:

- access an single port/application from a private network

#### remote port forwarding

forward (= send) from remote (`2222`) to a local (= receive) (`1111`)

```bash
ssh -R localhost:2222:localhost:1111 remote
```

use case:

- expose a single port/application from a public network to private one

#### dynamic port forwarding

forward (= send) from local (`1111`) to remote (= receive) (`all ports + interfaces`)

```bash
ssh -D localhost:1111 remote
```

use case:

- access a network (usually public network) from a private one
- open FireFox, add localhost:1111 as socks5 to access the remote network (`in local network`)

#### remote dynamic port forwarding (new feature) <sup>*what you need*</sup>

forward (= send) from remote to local (= receive) (`all ports + interfaces`)

```bash
ssh -R localhost:2222 remote
```

use case:

- expose a network (usually private network) to a public one
- open FireFox, add localhost:2222 as socks5 to access the local network (`in remote network`)

---

#### better dynamic port forwarding

```bash
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -fNTCD localhost:1234 remote

# -f : fork = go to background
# -N : N not command will be executed at remote 
# -T : no TTY
# -C : Compression on
# -D : dynamic
```

#### better remote dynamic port forwarding

```bash
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -fNTCR localhost:1234 remote

# -f : fork = go to background
# -N : N not command will be executed at remote 
# -T : no TTY
# -C : Compression on
# -R : remote
```

#### test access to/from dynamic/remote-dynamic port forwarding

```bash
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:PORT api.ipify.org
```

#### check which applications are connecting to

```bash
# on remote/local
lsof -ni :PORT
```

#### config file at `/home/$USER/.ssh/config`

```bash
Host remote 
    HostName a.b.c.d
    User username
    Port PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward.

On local side (Server S), start your openssh server server. This will start ssh server by default on port 22 - you could change this port in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, if necessary.

```
 service ssh start
```

On remote side (Client A), start a socks proxy AND set a remote port on the local side to connect to the socks proxy.

```
 ssh -N -D 127.0.0.1:8888 -p 22 <server-s>
 ssh -N -R 2222:127.0.0.1:8888 -p 22 <server-s>
```

On local side (Server S), use socks proxy setup on port 2222 via e.g. to connect to Google.

```
 curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:2222 https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't work. The Google page might appear, but that's only because you'll be accessing it through Server S; not Client A. You can verify this by launching `curl`on http://httpbin.org or http://icanhazip.com or http://api.ipify.org instead. Traffic will be routed through the local socks proxy, which essentially sends it to Server S again -- the initial purpose of `-D`.

Comment: Indeed the "ssh -D" process must not connect to the SSH server on _server-s_ but must connect to an SSH server on _Client A_.

Answer (score 0):

There is a replacement for `ssh` for this purpose called `ssf` that allows reverse dynamic socks to be created with the `-F` flag.

> The SSF client `-F port` option opens the given port on the SSF target server machine and forward SOCKS requests to the SSF client. The SSF client will act as the SOCKS server.
>
> https://securesocketfunneling.github.io/ssf/#how-to-use-socks

Assuming you have `ssfd` installed on the remote and `ssf` on the local you can set this up using ssh like so.

```
ssh -o"LocalCommand=ssf -F 1234 -p 10000 server" -f user@server ssfd -p 10000
```

This will allow the use of SOCKS on port 1234 on the remote server to access the internet through the client machine.

Comment: If you have OpenSSH 7.6+ client version or can install it Elad's answer is better.